# sql error code table

Tags: mysql, 2-3-4-tree

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`username` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
`password` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
`online` int(20) NOT NULL default '0′, 
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
`active` int(1) NOT NULL default '0′, 
`rtime` int(20) NOT NULL default '0′, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the original phpmyadmin error message, when I enter the code shown above sql to create the table:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'`password` varchar (32) NULL, `On-line` int NOT (20) NULL default '0 ', NON ' 
at line 4
```

I would like to understand how this code should be written correctly and what is wrong!

Comment: Strange, your code has 'online' column, but error message is complaining about 'on-line'.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove strange `'0′` quotes for `int` default values. This should work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `online` int(20) NOT NULL default 0,
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `active` int(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    `rtime` int(20) NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not closing you quotes correctly. You have `'0′` instead of `'0'`.

You can either fix them of get rid of the quotes at all, since the columns are defined as integer.